# Cron job running on wrong date in airflow

Tags: python, cron, airflow

My dag looks like this:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 6, 16),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=100),
    'provide_context': True
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    default_args=args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval='0 6 25 * *'
)
```

For reference, today is 7/26/2021. With the schedule_interval I have defined, I expect this to run on the 25th of each month at 6 am. However, when it ran yesterday (the 25th), the dag execution date was set to 6/25 at 6 am.

Why? I expected the execution date to be the 7/25. Is it something with my start_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Airflow, DAGs run at the *end* of a scheduling interval.  The `execution_date` is the date of the execution period while the `start_date` is the date in which the DAG/task began executing.  In your case, the `execution_date` is 6/25 as that was the date of the execution period.  The `start_date` would be 7/25.

The `execution_date` is a holdover from legacy ETL job scheduling where you would summarize data at the end of a period.

Comment: Are you saying I need to change my start_date to 7/25? I tried that and it still did not work.